# XSLT: Distinct names of child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

```
<mensagens>
        <mensagem maquina="M02" timestamp="2020-05-22T15:28:50+0000">
            <inicioAtividade>
                <contexto>
                    <tipo>OP</tipo>
                    <descricao>12345</descricao>
                </contexto>
            </inicioAtividade>
        </mensagem>

        <mensagem maquina="M03" timestamp="2020-05-22T15:29:46-0400">
            <fimAtividade>
                <contexto>
                    <tipo>OP</tipo>
                    <descricao>12345</descricao>
                </contexto>
            </fimAtividade>
        </mensagem>

        <mensagem maquina="M03" timestamp="2020-05-22T15:29:46-0400">
            <paragemForcada>
                <causa id="fdbs"/>
            </paragemForcada>
        </mensagem>

        <mensagem maquina="M02" timestamp="2020-05-22T18:28:46-0400">
            <consumo>
                <materiaPrima id="PC3025"/>
                <quantidade>200</quantidade>
                <origem>
                    <maquina id="M01"/>
                </origem>
            </consumo>
        </mensagem>

        <mensagem maquina="M01" timestamp="2020-05-23T15:28:46-0400">
            <producao>
                <produto id="PC3025"/>
                <quantidade>10</quantidade>
            </producao>
        </mensagem>

        <mensagem maquina="M03" timestamp="2020-06-22T15:28:46-0400">
            <entregaProducao>
                <quantidade>10</quantidade>
                <produto id="RC1.3"/>
                <deposito id="DEP1"/>
            </entregaProducao>
        </mensagem>

        <mensagem maquina="M01" timestamp="2020-05-31T15:28:46-0400">
            <estorno>
                <quantidade>10</quantidade>
                <materiaPrima id="RC1.2"/>
                <deposito id="DEP1"/>
            </estorno>
        </mensagem>
    </mensagens>
```

I'm trying to get all the names of child nodes of 'mensagem'.

Output would be: inicioAtividade, fimAtividade, paragemForcada, etc.

I already know how to get the child of mensagem name but I'm having trouble getting every distinct name

My template starts at mensagens

How could I get something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this XSLT expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(mensagem/*/name())" separator=", " />
```

Its output is

> inicioAtividade, fimAtividade, paragemForcada, consumo, producao, entregaProducao, estorno

To count each occurrence of a distinct name, you could use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/mensagens">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="mensagem/*" group-by="name()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(current-group()),' - ',current-grouping-key())" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is

```
1 - inicioAtividade
1 - fimAtividade
1 - paragemForcada
1 - consumo
1 - producao
1 - entregaProducao
1 - estorno
```

Comment: I tried it and I get an error saying the transformation failed :\

Comment: What failed, exactly?

Comment: I'm using genko on php and it just says invalid expression

Comment: You tagged this question XSLT-2.0. Does *genko*  support XSLT-2.0 or above?

Comment: Yes, that's the only reason I'm using it. I was actually using xlsx 3.0 but still wouldn't work

Comment: I noticed that the question title mentioned _distinct_ values. If this is indeed desired, the `distinct-values` function could be used in the xPath expression: `distinct-values(//mensagem/*/name())`.

Comment: Don't know what I'm missing

Comment: Don't know if its useful but my final goal was to count occurrences of type of message, for instance 1 of inicioAtividade, 1 of fimAtividade, and so on

Comment: Please add this code to your stylesheet and tell us the result: `<vendor><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></vendor>`. I strongly suspect you are NOT using an XSLT 2.0 processor. Note that if your stylesheet says version="2.0" and uses 2.0 constructs, and you run it using an XSLT 1.0 processor, you will get an error very similar to the one described.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, just tried your solution and worked flawlessly <3